# Raster layer unique report & Lat-Lon assignment

Tags: qgis, raster

I am working with QGIS 3.32.3-LIMA an working with Raster analysis Raster layer unique values report.
The report provides value, pixel count and area
Question: Is there a possibility that the report additionally assigng the Lat Lon coordinates for each value and pixel?

Comment: You only have one pixel per value?

Comment: Yes the model output (as tiff raster file)  has one pixel per value all with the same area.

Comment: I could think of two solutions: one is scripting to obtain the coordinates, or converting the raster pixels to points and obtain the coordinates

Comment: I used now the Rasterpixel to points tool. However, in the attribute table I just see the fid and the value, no lon-lat values. The input files hte tiff file is based on are georeferenced with lon-lat values for each pixel.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Raster Pixels to Points](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgispixelstopoints) to convert each pixel to a point
2. [Add geometry attributes](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisexportaddgeometrycolumns) to add x and y coordinates

[image]